IX4340 witn N and P channel MOSFET
In the datasheet I saw control of only N channel MOSFET, and the driver is positioned as low-side. However, one of its pins is inverted, so I think I can put a P-channel MOSFET there...
(I'm driving a segmented matrix of LEDs, so I need the load to be between the MOSFETs.)
Will this work?


What’s your Vcc voltage?

@winny 12vdc, drive voltage (INA, INB) - 3.3vdc

Could work yes. You need to invert your logic to INB though.

I'm not sure you need push-pull topology to drive the LEDs. The load betwen high and low side looks strange to me. Probabbly, single high-side or low-side switch should be good enough for you. In theory, both desing should be equal but I recommand to use high side switch (floating ground may lead to unexpeded problems because the load is pernamently connected to vcc and in case of short the load will conduct the current and it will not be possible to switch it off).
Additional, I take a look to datasheet and non of the channel is inverted!
Apart from the fact that the desing is apriopriate for your needs the IX4340 driver can be use as you describe as long as vcc is not higher then Vgs of the transistors, and transistors and driver use the same vcc.

This topology was used to reduce the number of power components in the circuit. The P channel mosfet connects power to one of the four matrix segments, and each N channel mosfet is connected to a specific color of all matrix segments. In any case, I haven't come up with another more optimized option :)

Neither of the channels of the IX4340 invert.
In that configuration, and if you control INA and INB with the same signal, there's never a condition where both MOSFETs are on, which would be required to apply power to the load. With OUTA=OUTB, either the N-channel transistor is on or the P-channel one is, but never both simultaneously.
You would require the signals at INA and INB to be inverted with respect to each other:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
It sounds like you're multiplexing, so you need to take care not to overlap ON states that may cause contention, and you should ensure that the driver \$V_{CC}\$ is the same as the P-channel source potential, but other than that, the idea should work.

Yes, I don’t know where I got the idea that one of the pins is inverted :) Now, for the convenience of board layout, I use IX4426/IX4427, so I don’t have to invert anything
